Can I use a PersistentIdentifier hashValue for UserNotifications identifier?
In a SwiftUI project using SwiftData, local notifications typically use a UUID as the notification identifier. But, since I’m using SwiftData and want to avoid having multiple unique identifiers in my model, can I stringify the hashValue of the PersistentIdentifier and use that instead?
Should this be ok?
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

class NotificationManager {
    static let shared = NotificationManager()
    
    func scheduleNotification(for item: Item) {
        let notificationId = String(item.id.hashValue)
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Items"
        content.body = "Itemize the items"
        content.sound = .default

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationId, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to schedule notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeNotification(for item: Item) {
        let notificationId = String(item.id.hashValue)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [notificationId])
    }
}


Does it matter as long as the value is unique enough for your needs?

Maybe too unique? Think i just found the issue in the documentation:
"Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions of your program. Do not save hash values to use during a future execution." hashValue

The problem is the hashValue is unstable and will change between executions of the app.
From hashValue documentation:

Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions
of your program. Do not save hash values to use during a future
execution.

The best solution at the moment seems to be storing a notificationId in my model which imho does look a lot more cleaner than a hacky extension to extract the UUID from the id.
Updated code takes a UUID (notificationId) persisted in the Item model:
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

class NotificationManager {
    static let shared = NotificationManager()
    
    func scheduleNotification(for item: Item) {
        let notificationId = item.notificationId.uuidString
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Items"
        content.body = "Itemize the items"
        content.sound = .default

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationId, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to schedule notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeNotification(for item: Item) {
        let notificationId = item.notificationId.uuidString
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [notificationId])
    }
}

